# Como trabajar con parámetros de salida en la capa persistencia c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

**Tengo este SP en SQL server:**

```
create proc sp_NombreEP
    @cod varchar(150),
    @nombreEp  varchar(200) output as
begin
    select @nombreEp = nombreE from Tramites where codigo = @cod
end
```

**En VS 2010 hice esta función para poder agarrar el parámetro de salida:**

```
public static string NombreE(string pCodigo) {           
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Constantes.CONEXION);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_NombreEP", cnn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", pCodigo);
            SqlParameter prmNombre = new SqlParameter();
            prmNombre.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            prmNombre.ParameterName = "@nombreEp";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prmNombre);
            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataReader lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //No se como continuar acá.. esta es mi duda.
            cnn.Close();
            return null;
        }
}
```

Sería de mucha ayuda que me guíen, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas parametro de salida para el caso que planteas, podrias usar el `ExecuteScalar()`

Defines el procedure de esta forma

```
create proc sp_NombreEP
    @cod varchar(150)
begin
    select nombreE from Tramites where codigo = @cod
end
```

Y lo invocas usando

```
public static string NombreE(string pCodigo) 
{           
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Constantes.CONEXION))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_NombreEP", cnn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", pCodigo);

        return Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

asi de simple el ExecuteScalar() devolvera el nombre asociado con el codigo

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con parámetros de salida, primero debes quitar el ExecuteReader y usar en su lugar ExecuteNonQuery. Despues lees el valor con el objeto de tu parámetro:

```
   ...
   ...
   cnn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   string outputValue = prmNombre.Value.ToString();

   cnn.Close();
```