# ¿Cómo mostrar un dato de salida de un procedimiento almacenado en un TexBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedure

Tengo un ***procedimiento almacenado*** donde tengo un dato de salida *output*, que me genera un código, quisiera poder mostrar ese dato en un *TextBox*, pero no consigo la manera. Utilizo *Sql Server* y *Visual Studio* con *C#* en programación a 3 capas.

Mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
create proc sp_generarCodigoautomatico1
    (@codigopr varchar(7) output)
    as  
    if(SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Products) = 0
        SET @codigoprov = 'PRO001'
    ELSE
        SET
        @codigopr=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Products)+1
```

En mi capa datos:

```
public void GenerarCodigo(CD_Prod parametros)
{
    using(var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using(var comando = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "sp_autogenerarCodigo";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                  
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigopro", 
            parametros.CodGenerado).Direction = 
            ParameterDirection.Output;
        }
    }
}
```

En mi capa `negocio` lo llamo asi:

```
public void GenerarCodigo(string generarcodigo)
{
    dPro.CodGenerado = generarcodigo;
    dPro.GenerarCodigo(dPro);
}
```

El procedimiento almacenado que muestro es para generar un código al insertar un nuevo registro, y quiero que eso se muestre en una caja de texto y no, esa no es mi *llave primaria*, mi *llave primaria* es un ***Id entero autonumérico***, tengo otro campo de nombre `código` para que se guarde el *código generado*. He visto videos de *Visual Basic*, pero llego hasta este punto, no sé cómo mostrarlo en un *TextBox* en *C#*.

Comment: como estas ejecutando tu procedimiento almacenado en C#? al final de donde ejecutas deberias indicarle que tu retorne el output, pero neceitamos ver mas tu codigo, edita la pregunta y pega tu codigo.

Comment: esta pregunta tiene alguna relacion con esta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327685/como-trabajar-con-par%c3%a1metros-de-salida-en-la-capa-persistencia-c  porque me parece mucha casualidad que se generaron casi al mismo tiempo y plantean la ejecucion de procedure con parametros de output

Comment: No, no tienen nada que ver, es mera casualidad, ya edito la pregunto y coloco el codigo

Comment: ah ya jejeje, @Manny

Comment: @ArtEze supongo asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de como aplicarlo en tu proyecto en capas.
Cambie el output por un return.

```
 create proc sp_generarCodigoautomatico1

as  
declare @codigopr int
if(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Products) = 0
    SET @codigoprov = 'PRO001'
ELSE
    SET
    @codigopr=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Products)+1
    Return @codigopr
```

En C# puedes capturar el return del store procedure asi:

```
 public int GenerarCodigo()
    {
        int resultado = 0;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_autogenerarCodigo", connection);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter returnValue = command.Parameters.Add("return_value", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        returnValue.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        connection.Open();
        Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
        resultado = (int)returnValue.Value;
        connection.Close();
        return resultado;
    }
```

como te repito no se como aplicarlo en capas, pero aqui ya solo ejecutas la funcion GenerarCodigo() y el resultado o mas bien el return se la asignas a tu label o textbox, siento no poder ayudarte mas, suerte!!. :)

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo una duda yo declare mi codigo en varchar porque es una combinacion de letras y numeros pero en C# lo colocas en int, a que se debe eso?

Comment: puedes cambiarlo a tu necesidad, si quieres que sea varchar solo cambia el tipo y como lo recibes en C# y listo.

Comment: @Nathy y la funcion tambien cambia a public String GenerarCodigo() para que no te marque error en el return.

Comment: hice los cambios y me salio esto
´Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PROV001' to data type int.´

Comment: @Nathy en que linea te sle ese error?

Comment: en el ExcecuteNonQuery

Comment: lo puedes usar asi Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteNonQuery()); o solo ocupa asi command.ExecuteNonQuery(); y todo lo que tenga int cambialo a string y funcionara.